# Android PHP GET Base64

Tags: php, android, database

I want to parse some data from my android app to my website. One of the data is a pdf and the other bunch are just integers or strings. My attempt in saving the data works except if I want to parse the base64 string that contains the pdf. In the database the new inserted row is null in every field. What I want to do after I retrieve the base64 string is to make a BLOB with the base64 string.

Android

```
 //Read text from file
            BufferedReader input = null;
            input = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(openFileInput(myFile)));
            String line;
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line + "\n");
            }
            String text = buffer.toString();

            byte[] byteArray = text.getBytes("UTF-8");

            String base64= Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);

            Log.d("HERE I AM", base64);

            url = new URL("http://website.com/kundenexecute.php" +
                    "?firstname=" + firstname + "&"
                    + "lastname=" + lastname + "&"
                    + "postalcode=" + postalcode + "&"
                    + "citytext=" + citytext + "&"
                    + "address=" + address + "&"
                    + "e_mail=" + e_mail + "&"
                    + "birthday=" + birthday+ "&"
                    + "test=" + base64);
            //  + "pdf=" + blobData);


            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream a = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            postalcode = String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(convertStreamToString(a)));
            urlConnection.disconnect();
```

PHP File

```
<?php       
include "db.inc.php";
include "redirect.php";
session_start();

$conn = mysqli_connect($db_server, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name)  or die("you did not connect bozo");


$postleitzahl = $_GET['postalcode'];
$firstname = $_GET['firstname'];
$lastname = $_GET['lastname'];
$citytext = $_GET['citytext'];
$address = $_GET['address'];
$e_mail = $_GET['e_mail'];
$birthday=$_GET['birthday'];
$test=$_GET['test'];

//echo " base64 string";
echo $test;

$statement = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO kunden(kunden_plz, kunden_nachname, kunden_vorname, kunden_adresse, kunden_ort, kunden_email, kunden_geburtsdatum) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

$statement->bind_param("sssssss", $postleitzahl,       $firstname,$lastname,$citytext,$address,$e_mail,$birthday);
$statement->execute();
```

?>

How my Database looks before I try with base64 and without

[Database picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3epl3.png)

Comment: `String text = buffer.toString();`. That will not contain your pdf file. You cannof put a pdf file in a string as such a file is no text. You also cannot use a BufferedReader and readLine to read a pdf file.

Comment: I would not do that with a GET : likely you are busting the maximum URL length somewhere down the network path to your server. I would POST all your params in a JSON, with content type `application/json`, and php-side json_decode the payload.

Comment: How do I do this? I tried to do it with a POST once but it always was null or it never even came to the database in the first place.

Comment: About the pdf, how do I retrieve it now?